# I am getting an RPC error message when running my cucumber tests against a password protected https url

Tags: https, cucumber, yaml, rpc, poltergeist

So what am I using:

I am using the following gems on Ruby 1.9.3:

> capybara, commander, cucumber, cucumber-rails, fakeweb, factory_girl_rails, flexmock, gherkin, parallel, parallel_tests, poltergeist, rspec, rspec-rails, sauce, sauce-connect, sauce-cucumber, selenium-webdriver'

For my config file I am using yaml. so config.yml

Now to access the homepage of the site I am testing in my config I have

```
base_url: https://<username>:<password>@the.url.com
```

When running my cucumber tests (using poltergeist) the following message is shown several times while the tests are running:

> Invalid rpc message origin. https://username@the.url.com vs https://the.url.com

It does not cause the tests to fail but is incredibly untidy and I would really like to get rid of it.

I have been, and still am, investigating a solution to this but if someone gets there first that would be amazing.

Some things that I have tried/know what is happening:-

I know my tests are working as I have run them using the browser (firefox) and it is fine with none of these messages. 
Also if I remove the s from https the message dissapears. But alas that will not work for the site as require https. 
Putting the url in double quotes does not solve the problem. 
I have pinpointed the issue directly to the config and specifying the UN and PW in the url.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your username and password have gone AWOL:

> Invalid rpc message origin. https://@the.url.com vs https://the.url.com

The first part should be `https://username:password@the.url.com`. Could it be because your config is lacking the double slashes?

> base_url: https:<username>:<password>@the.url.com

should probably be

> base_url: https://<username>:<password>@the.url.com

Comment: Noted, the formating here seems to be going mad with my characters. Let me try and get rid of my typos. :(

Comment: Note for anyone looking to answer this post, This answer mentioning that the Username and password going awol only pointed out a typo whilst logging this question. I can confirm that both the correct username and password are passed in the string. Also the error msg (quite correctly) omits the password and only keeps the username.